# Do Violet's clothes turn invisible?

Tags: incredibles-2

At the very beginning of *Incredibles 2*, we see Violet handing off babysitting to Dash in the form of an unmanned strolled zooming across to him:

[image: Violet and Jack-Jack]

In this scene, she turns completely invisible (though I can't find an image of it).

**However**, in the scene after she comes back from her "date with Tony" (the one that Tony missed because his memory was wiped), Violet's clothes are still visible:

[image: Violet takes ice cream from the fridge]

---

**So, do Violet's clothes actually turn invisible, or not?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Her clothes don't, her Incredibles suit does. Because back in *The Incredibles*, Edna created

> A sturdy material which will disappear completely, as she does.

Shortly after, when Violet saw her suit for the first time, and it turning invisible with her, she was amazed, indicating she had never encountered such a thing before.

As seen at the end of *The Incredibles* or in the comic *Disney•Pixar The Incredibles 2: Heroes at Home* (2018), Violet wears her costume underneath her clothes. Of course, this is a regular trope for superheroes, but it's more of a *necessity* for Violet's activity as a Super, since, even though each Incredibles costumes is adapted to its owner, Dash can still run in everyday clothes, Helen can still stretch, etc.

Violet can't use her stealth if she has civilian clothes on (unless she's naked, which isn't handy on a battlefield). Thus, Violet has to fit with "superhero wears their costume underneath clothes".

[image: Violet tells Dash she wears her costume underneath her clothes]

Answer (score 9):

[When Helen meets with Edna Mode in the first film](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iOpH6E7T6I0) she demonstrates that each of the costumes she provides to the Parr family are tailored specifically to their powers, including Violet's super suit turning invisible along with her.

> Your daughter's suit was tricky. But I finally created a 
>   sturdy material that will disappear completely as she does.

However, Violet's other clothing is not made out of the same material and thus does not become invisible along with her.

Comment: The last time I watched the film was, maybe, 10 years ago! Thanks for this (+1), but do you think you could get me a scene or a time so I can check it out for myself?

Answer (score 1):

The other two answers are correct in that Edna creates her super suit so that it can turn invisible as she does.

> **Edna:** Your daughter's suit was tricky. But I finally created a sturdy material that will disappear completely as she does.
>
> <sub>*The Incredibles*</sub>

However, to be complete in *The Incredibles* we also see her turn invisible hiding from Tony outside of school and her clothes are seen whilst she is hidden.

[image: Violet hides from Tony]